# SVN: how to solve 'file has been replaced' status

Tags: svn, coda

I was modifying files renaming them and switching them around (I was testing alternative homepages). Now I get a status message that says 'File has been replaced' and an R. I'm not sure what to do to solve this.  I'm using Coda, and it does not solve it. So i guess it's command line time. The version that I care about is my local version, and I want to overwrite the remote version. i'm the only person working on it so a brute force approach is fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Copy the file and put it in a temp location
2. Run "svn revert "
3. Now copy it back to the same location
4. Run "svn st " to check status

Answer (score 1):

i fixed it by simply committing. it for some reason code did not do this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I used a similar procedure to that explained by Version Control Buddy to correct this issue in RAD with Subversive SVN Connector (Eclipse may be similar):

1. List item
2. Copy the file(s) to a temp location outside of RAD
3. Revert the file(s) in RAD using Right-click > Team > Revert
4. Outside of RAD, copy the saved back to the location
5. Refresh the folder in RAD, and the correct status will show.

Note that I find if I just directly check in a file that is showing as Replace, the history of the original file is not easily view-able, so it may be worth these steps to preserve the history, especially on a multi-user project.