# Howto turn svn status "replaced" into "modified"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, entity-framework-4.1, t4, visualsvn

I use EF4.1, Visualstudio 2010, VisualSVN.
I changed (damaged) the model in a way, that none of the edmx-files could be generated. All of these files are removed from the Project then. Then I fixed the model, so the files are generated again and re-added to the project. But now subversion reports all those files as "replaced". 
How can I turn this "feature" off, or at least, how can I deal with it in an easy way?
(Easier than remove/svn-revert/copyback)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVN: how to solve 'file has been replaced' status](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391945/svn-how-to-solve-file-has-been-replaced-status)